# async / await not working in combination with fetch

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api, ecmascript-next

I'm trying to use ES7 `async` / `await` together with `fetch`. I know I'm close but I can't get it to work. Here is the code:

```
class Bar {
    async load() {
        let url =  'https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/goog/quote?format=json';
        try {
            response = await fetch(url);
            return response.responseText;
        } catch (e) {
            return e.message;
        }
    }
}
```

which I use as follows:

```
let bar = new Bar();
bar.load().then(function (val) {
    console.log(val);
});
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmNBEJ)

For some reason I always get into the `catch` with the message

```
response is not defined
```

Any suggestions what I do wrong ?

UPDATE: As suggested in the comments, it might be an issue with `fetch`, so I tried a simplified (ES5) version:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>      
        <script>
            var url =  'https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/goog/quote?format=json';
            fetch(url, {method: 'get', mode: 'cors'}).then(function (response) {
                       console.log(response.responseText);
               });
        </script>
    <head>

   <body></body>
<html>
```

And still doesn't work :( However, if I replace fetch it works:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, false);
request.send(null);
console.log(request.responseText);
```

Comment: I think you're using fetch wrong - if fetch is this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Still not sure what is wrong. I've tried adding `{method: 'get'}` to the `fetch` call but didn't work.

Comment: Also looks like you're hitting a CORS issue

Comment: I've updated the post with a es5 version + fetch which also doesn't work. I don't see any CORS arros

Comment: I didn't say it was an "issue with fetch" ... I said "I think you are using fetch wrong" - that aside, `finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols` definitely supplies **zero** CORS headers, so you are having a CORS issue

Comment: Interesting. without `fetch` it works. So the question is if it is possible to ignore CORS

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You forgot to declare `response` as a variable. Class code is always strict code, and you won't get away with assigning to [implictly global variables](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Instead, it throws a `ReferenceError`.

Apart from that, [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) objects don't have a `responseText` property like a XHR, they do have a `.text()` method that waits for the body to be received and returns a promise.

```
class Bar {
    async load() {
        let url =  'https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/goog/quote?format=json';
        try {
            let response = await fetch(url);
//          ^^^^
            return await response.text();
//                                ^^^^^^
        } catch (e) {
            return e.message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, thats it. Is there a reason why you have the second `await` ? Without it the code also works because the first `await` already resolved the fetch promise.

Comment: Awaiting the second promise means that errors in it would be thrown into your try-catch, not propagated right away to reject the returned promise. So not much of a difference. If the try-catch wasn't there, the solutions with and without should be exactly equivalent.

Comment: I'd be very interested to know why this works as the responses from yahoo.com do not allow CORS, and replacing the original codepen code with this code doesn't make it work.