# Is there any benefit to making a function async when it returns a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

When you have a function that doesn't await anything and returns a promise you can do this. This will return a promise that you can `await`.

```
function doSomethingAamzing ({id, animalType, accessToken}) {
  const url = `${url}/v1/${animalType}/${id}?access_token=${accessToken}`
  return request.get(url)
}
```

It's not necessary but we can do this.

```
async function doSomethingAamzing ({id, animalType, accessToken}) {
  const url = `${url}/v1/${animalType}/${id}?access_token=${accessToken}`
  return await request.get(url)
}
```

In the latter is easier to read as a developer that the function is async and will return a promise, which isn't very clear in the first function. The only reason I can think that it might be better practice to use the latter is if the code undergone some static code analysis that could benefit from the explicit `async` syntax.

Is there any benefit to making a function async when it returns a promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is not observable from outside (unless you get the function source via `toString`, not supported by current transpilers anyway), so there's no benefit here.

Making the function `async` might even slow it down a bit because the invocation involves more things, creating a new promise and resolving it.

The big advantage of `async` functions, apart from the increased maintainability you've already mentioned, is the error handling. Any exceptions thrown in the evaluation of the function body will be converted to a rejection of the returned promise, without needing to be explicit about this.

Notice you don't even need to use `await` here, you can `return` thenables directly<sup>1</sup> from `async function`s:

```
async function doSomethingAamzing ({id, animalType, accessToken}) {
  const url = `${url}/v1/${animalType}/${id}?access_token=${accessToken}`
  return request.get(url)
}
```

<sub>1: unless you are `return`ing inside a `try` block, where it [does make a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823277/async-await-not-working-in-combination-with-fetch/32824050#comment53483870_32824050).</sub>